# Solve the differential equation: $y''+(1-2x)y'+2x(e^{x^{2}}-1)y=xe^{x^{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have an exercise of solving the equation above using MATLAB, with a hint to set $ v(x)=(y'+y)e^{-x^{2}} $. I tried to do with my hand and get the following: $ v'+2xy=x $, but I don't know what to do next, I'm stuck there.

My teacher asked to not using the "dsolve" function, so I'm stuck with MATLAB too.

Anyone can do this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: `ode45` is a Matlab function which solves differential equations numerically. Do you know if you can use it for this problem?

Comment: I think I can't. This problem is about symbolic calculation. I think the route is to turn the equation into a separating of variables one, and use "int", but the last equation I got is not kind of variables separated.

Comment: @Steve: Using $y'$ from the hint, did you find $y''$ and substitute back into the ODE?

Comment: @Amzoti: I find $ v' $ and substitute to the equation, after reducing, I get $ v' + 2xy = x $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did well so far. You found $v'(x)=x-2xy(x)$. The substitution given in the hint can be transformed to $y'=v(x)e^{x^2}-y(x)$. This now constitutes a system of two coupled differential equations.

You may want to compare the numerical solution of this compact system to the one generated from the system using the standard substitution $v(x)=y'(x)$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm kind of dumb but is that system solvable? My teacher said I should use the hint to transform the equation to a first order differential equation. How do you think about this hint?

Comment: I would think this hint was provided to be able to reduce this to a separable equation that you can solve. It was likely a constructed example to make that the case, is just my guess.

Comment: Please give the exact wording of your task. 'Solve with Matlab' says numerical solution to me. It is a linear system, so one can compute an approximation for the fundamental matrix of the homogeneous system and then with that a particular solution for the inhomogeneous system. The systems matrix is

$$A(x)=\begin{bmatrix}-1& e^{x^2}\\-2x&0\end{bmatrix},$$

the system for the fundamental matrix is $\Phi'(x)=A(x)\Phi(x)$ with $\Phi(0)=I_2$.

Comment: @LutzL: The problem is a question from my basic MATLAB class final test. I've just learnt the basics, so your solution seems a little bit hard for me to understand. The exact question is: 

Suppose $ \left\{\begin{matrix}
y''+(1-2x)y'+2x(e^{x^{2}}-1)y=xe^{x^{2}}\\ 
y''(0)=1, \ y(0)=2
\end{matrix}\right.\\ $

By letting $ v(x)=(y'+y)e^{-x^{2}} $, turn the equation to first-order and solve without using dsolve.
Thank you LutzL and Amzoti :)

Comment: Then the task really is just to transform the problem into usable input for ode45, without resorting to the symbolic capabilities of matlab. The system of first order needs to be encoded as a function dotyv=f(x,yv), where yv is a two-component vector, as is the result dotyv, and you need to find the initial value of $y'(0)$.